# Geofence in gmap3

Tags: jquery, google-maps, jquery-gmap3

I want to add a geofence in gmap3. I thought the most basic way would be to draw a circle and check if the marker is within the bounds of the circle, when the marker is added.

I added a circle

```
var fence = $('#dispatcher').gmap3(
  { action: 'addCircle',
    circle:{
      options:{
        center: [53.99212, -1.541812],
        radius : 3000,
        fillColor : "#FFAF9F",
        strokeColor : "#FF512F" 
      }
    }
  }
);
```

Any idea how would I get the bounds to check against?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe using

```
circle.getBounds();
```

it's listed here [Google maps V3 API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Circle), then using [contains(latLng:LatLng)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds)

Comment: cheers, this is the method i want to use. My issue is implementation. how can i select the circle to call getBounds()

Comment: Surely the fence var should have some kind of reference to the actual Gmaps Circle obj, have you tried to use firebug or Chrome inspector in that obj ?